# Error with module using Cloud Storage with Python and his tutorial

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

I'm trying to test Google Cloud Storage to store images (I need it in an app that I'm developing) and I'm following the [Bookshelf App tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/python/getting-started/using-cloud-storage#app_structure) that they have in his webpage.

I'm using python and the problem is that when I execute the requirementes.txt all packages have been installed fine, but when I try execute the code, I see this error:

```
...sandbox.py", line 948, in load_module
    raise ImportError('No module named %s' % fullname)
ImportError: No module named cryptography.hazmat.bindings._openssl
```

I have been trying hundred of posibles solutions, reinstalling only the cryptography package, trying to use different versions of the same module, and installing other packages that contains it but anything resolved the problem.

The requirements contains this:

```
Flask==0.10.1
gcloud==0.9.0
gunicorn==19.4.5
oauth2client==1.5.2
Flask-SQLAlchemy==2.1
PyMySQL==0.7.1
Flask-PyMongo==0.4.0
PyMongo==3.2.1
six==1.10.0
```

I'm sure that it is a simple error but I don't find the way to solve it.
Any help will be welcome. Thanks.

EDIT:

When I try do this with a python program this work fine:

```
import os
from gcloud import storage

os.environ['GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS'] = 'key.json'

client = storage.Client(project='xxxxxxx')
bucket = client.get_bucket('yyyyyyy')
f = open('profile.jpg', 'rb')
blob = bucket.blob(f.name)
blob.upload_from_string(f.read(), 'image/jpeg')
url = blob.public_url
print url
```

Why I don't can use gcloud library without erros in a GAE app?

Comment: Looking at the installation page for the library cryptography https://cryptography.io/en/latest/installation/, it looks like it is not pure Python. App Engine only supports running pure Python code. I don't know what package from the ones you are using depends on cryptography library. An alternative would be using Managed VMs.

Comment: You're right, but if in this tutorial they used this package in App Engine is because is possible use it. Therefore i don't understand where is the bug when I try  make the same example. Thanks you.

Comment: You are right, this should work, I see the project uses Managed VMs.

Comment: Please check the section that I added, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you're following the bookshelf tutorial, but according to this line in your stacktrace:

```
...sandbox.py", line 948, in load_module
```

It hints that you're using `dev_appserver.py` to run the code. This isn't necessary for Managed VMs/Flexible unless you're using the [compat](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/migrating-an-existing-app) runtime.

If this is the case, the [tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/python/getting-started/using-cloud-storage#run_the_app_on_your_local_computer) provides correct instructions:

```
$ virtualenv env
$ source env/bin/activate
$ pip install -r requirements.txt
$ python main.py
```

(If this is not the case, please feel free to comment on this with more details about how you're running your application).